# Windows snap assist: How to move the divider using only the keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, aero-snap, windows-snap-assist

I like the Windows Snap function and use the keyboard to do it quickly.  After using Windows-LeftArrow I can then choose what Window should be put on the right side with arrow keys and enter.

This is very nice, except I also sometimes wish for the divider to be not placed exactly in the middle.  I can then grab the mouse and pull the division to either side.

I would like to do this division move using only the keyboard but I am not experienced enough with Windows 10 to guess what combination to use.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Snap can only be customized as in *Settings > System > Multitasking*:

---

[image]

---

For more control, you would need to look at third-party tools.

The best is perhaps the free [GridMove](http://www.dcmembers.com/jgpaiva/),
with a [tutorial](http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/?topic=11534.0),
with which you may define any grid that you like.

A commercial alternative with a free version is
[AquaSnap](https://www.nurgo-software.com/products/aquasnap).

Comment: I am not as such interested in changing anything.  I just need the keyboard shortcut that allows me to move the divider.

Comment: As far as I know, that feature does not exist. Windows Snap is built into the Windows code and is not modifiable, except by Microsoft.

Comment: Yes.  I understand that.  Question was whether there was a keyboard shortcut to do this, that I am just not aware of but might be available and perhaps even publicly documented.  Have I phrased my question badly?

Comment: As far as I know, my above answer contains all available information on the subject.